# maxlength attribute not working in lightning:input for number type

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

maxlength attribute in  is not working.
Is there any alternative ways for this isuue or any suggestion?

Reffrence: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleInputNumber

Comment: can you should me with your code and some screen shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle through javascript handler, here is code:

--Component--

```
<aura:component >
    <lightning:input type="number" aura:id="number" name="input1" 
                     label="Enter a number" maxlength="3" onchange="{!c.CheckLength}"/>
</aura:component>
```

-- Controller.js----

```
({
    CheckLength : function(component, event, helper) {
        var val = component.find("number").get('v.value');
        if(val.length > 3){
            var comp = component.find("number");
            comp.set('v.value',val.substring(0,3));
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You could specify a minimum and maximum value. It won't prevent input values outside the range, but will highlight it with a red error message:

```
<lightning:input label="Some Field" max="9999" min="0" />
```

Be sure to [check validity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm) before saving if you use this technique.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
If I enter decimal value it's fire error, so I used step attribute.
But I want to enter value in 3.2(Ex.99.25) format for percent field.
Do you have any suggetion for percent field?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while now, but, the [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example) component now prevents entering additional characters when the set limit has been reached and optionally displays an error message:

```
<lightning:input maxlength="255" required="true" label="Subject" name="Subject" value="{!v.subjectValue}" messageWhenValueMissing="Complete this field." messageWhenTooShort=" " />
```

Example (when empty and field is required):

[image]

Example (When limit reached):
[image]

**the char counter is custom, added for visibility purposes.

Comment: It still doesn't work for number type